# Create "Default Values or Binding" for new coumn having Data-Type of DateTimeOffset(7)?

Tags: sql-server, datetimeoffset

When you create a new table in the database and you added a new column, having data-type of DateTimeOffset(7).

What do you use as "Default Values or Binding" for this DateTimeOffset as default?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() function.  I think it is the one you want to use to get the full advantage of the data type.

Other date functions can be found here.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx

Last but not least, the code below creates a table in tempdb and inserts 100 records with defaults only.

```
-- Sample table
create table tempdb.dbo.my_table
(
my_id int identity(1,1),
my_date datetimeoffset (7) default SYSDATETIMEOFFSET ( )
);
go

-- Add data
declare @cnt int = 0;
while (@cnt < 100)
begin
    insert tempdb.dbo.my_table default values;
    set @cnt = @cnt + 1;
end
go

-- Take a look
select * from tempdb.dbo.my_table
go
```